# Уместно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Уместно ли здесь двоеточие, занесённое в скобки?

***Вот я и посмотрю(:) изменилась ты или нет.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Двоеточие можно поставить, но это не единственный вариант.**

Постановка двоеточия при бессоюзной связи предполагает увеличенную паузу (а это не всегда удобно для разговорного текста), но это предложение можно представить и как СПП с двумя однородными придаточными, связанными одиночным союзом ИЛИ:
**Вот я и посмотрю, изменилась ты или нет.**

Такие варианты часто встречаются, например:
...я съезжу и посмотрю, нравится мне это или нет… [Л. Р. Кабо. Ровесники Октября (1964)]

У Розенталя есть пример с союзом ЛИ...ИЛИ (повторяющимся, поэтому ставится запятая):
*Налево все небо над горизонтом было залито багровым заревом, и трудно было понять, был **ли** то где-нибудь пожар, **или** же собиралась всходить луна* (Чехов).

[ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что двоеточие тут уместно.

Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать и т. п., делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь описание.

[Пунктуация - Двоеточие | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/157-dvoe)